# Runtime error 438 when calling a public procedure

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

When the procedure *protectAllWorksheets* is executed, a runtime error 438 is raised and I don't understand why.

```
Public Sub protectAllWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        protectWorksheet (ws)            <------------- Runtime Error 438
    Next ws
End Sub

Public Sub protectWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Rubberduck's code inspection also raises 2 errors at this line:

- Argument with incomptaible object type
- Object used where a value is required

If I replace the error line by the code in *protectWorksheet* (so direct execution instead of calling a sub-procedure), the code executes smoothly. The same thing happens for every sub-procedure calling with 'Worksheet' or 'Workbook' required in argument.

In the Local Variables Window, when I open *ws* properties i, it opens Outlook and tries to create a Profile (since I don't have any). Yet ws's name and other properties are correct, so ws actually exists and points to the 1st sheet of ThisWorkbook. Really weird behavior.

I searched on internet, looked at Microsoft docs but I can't figure out what causes the error here.

Comment: PS: I tried to run it on a newly created Workbook, and same error occurs.

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `protectWorksheet ws`. Also it seems that `strPassword` is a `Public` variable here ... it probably should be a parameter of `protectWorksheet`.

Comment: It works, thank you for the help. I really feel stupid right now.

Comment: This is not the first or last time that someone will be bitten by parentheses :-)

Comment: ```strPassword``` is a Module Const since I use it in other procedures.
I haven't touch VBA in a while and forgot this parentheses thing since other languages don't have it !

Comment: Why would you be tempted to surround the object with parens in the first place? All that does is evaluate the expression within the parens and doing that returns the value of the drault property of the object... which does not match the signature of the Sub being called.

Comment: You're correct, I forget this feature of OOP. Then how can I pass the object and not its default property ? I also had this issue in a ```IF Statement``` where I couldn't pass ```ThisWorkbook``` in a function returning a Boolean.

Comment: Just DON'T USE parens. `protectWorksheet ws`

Comment: Yes that I understood well and don't worry I won't use them anymore. But I'm talking about the ```IF``` Statement ? Is it possible to call a function passing an argument such as ```ThisWorkbook``` (as an object, not default attribute obviously) ?

Comment: Yes it's very possible to do this: `Public Function BookName(ByVal wb As Workbook)`, `Debug.Print wb.Name`, `End Function`, and then call `BookName ThisWorkbook`. Or if it's any clearer to you, `BookName wb:=ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from @BigBen comment:

Remove the parentheses: `protectWorksheet ws`